# tikzpicture shift

Tags: tikz-pgf

I exported the code for the following graph from GeoGebra.
[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\begin{axis}[
x=1cm,y=1cm,
axis lines=middle,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=-2,
xmax=4,
ymin=-1,
ymax=2,
]
\draw [shift={(2,0)},line width=1pt]  (0,0) --  plot[domain=1.1780972450961726:1.5707963267948966,variable=\t]({1*1*cos(\t r)+0*1*sin(\t r)},{0*1*cos(\t r)+1*1*sin(\t r)}) -- cycle ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But the above code gives the following graph.

[image]

And the issue was resolved by adjusting `[shift={(2,0)},line width=1pt]`
to `[shift={(2cm,0cm)},line width=1pt]` or `[shift={(2-2,0-1)},line width=1pt]`
where -2,-1 come from xmin=-2, ymin=-1.

I was wondering why the initial code does not work and if there is a way to type 'cm' in `[shift={(2,0)},line width=1pt]` as above at once in case there are lots of `\draw[shift={(,)}]`'s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Desired image you can reproduce width:

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\begin{axis}[
x=1cm,y=1cm,
axis lines=middle,
grid,
xmin=-2,    xmax=4,
ymin=-1,    ymax=2,
]
\draw [xshift=2cm, line width=1pt]  (0,0) --  plot[domain=1.1780:1.570,variable=\t] ({cos(\t r)},{sin(\t r)}) -- cycle ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- `shift` in drawing function doesn't work as you expected. You need to replace it with `xshift=..., yshift=...`
- for amount of shift you need to add unit, default values are in `pt`
- your original code has a lot clutter: `1*?1*cos(\t r)` is shortly `cos(\t r)` etc

Answer (score 0):

Lately, Geogebra translates to pgfplots code, but for this task I prefer Tikz

```
    \documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \draw[gray, opacity=0.5, xstep=2cm, ystep=1] (-2,-1) grid (4,2);
    \draw[->] (-2,0)-- (4,0) ;
    \draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,2) ;
    \draw (2,0) -- (2,1) arc (90:67.5:1) --cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
 
or with axis labels
 
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \draw[gray, opacity=0.5, xstep=2cm, ystep=1] (-2,-1) grid (4,2);
    \draw[->] (-2,0)-- (4,0) node[pos=0.97, above] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,2) node[pos=0.94, right] {$y$};
    \draw (2,0) -- (2,1) arc (90:67.5:1) --cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

It's simpler.
[image]